# Cannot Connect to Azure SQL Server using SQL Authenntication

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, firewall, connectivity

So here is my situation.  I have an azure sql server that i am trying to connect to.

If i try to connect with AAD w/Universal MFA it works fine.
If i try to connect with SQL authentication it fails.  My ip is in the firewall exception list.

I have tried it on multiple machines, on multiple networks, even going so far as to set up an azure vm and trying it from there, but no luck.

This worked previously up until a few weeks ago, and as far as i can tell nothing was changed.

Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated!

[image]

Error Message
ectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

Comment: Can you please share what error you are getting?

Comment: add an screenshot of the error, also, have you tried to use the query editor of Azure?

Comment: I added in the error message.  I can get to it in azure query editor and for some reason my boss can still get to it (this is actually running in code, but I figure if I can't get in vi Sql management studio, there iss the problem).

Comment: My ip is in the firewall on azure.  Like i said, i even tried setting up a VM under the same tenant and can't get in.  So, yeah, I'm stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login to SQL Server is working.

A SQL login is mapped to a database user.

The problem is that the default database for "BlackbirdAdmin" is master, and the "BlackbirdAdmin" login is not mapped to a database user in master.